# JavaScript no funciona con WebView compilada en Swift IOS

Tags: javascript, web, swift, webview

espero puedan ayudarme, Realice un sitio web que consta de un formulario, obviamente dicho formulario cuenta con validaciones en sus campos que las realice con javascript (validaciones para que campos no se vayan vacíos etc…) el sitio funciona bien, el problema esta que cree un WebView en Swift y la parte de JavaScript no funciona bien, todas las validaciones que hice se las salta, previamente también hice un webView en Android y tuve que habilitar Javascript con esta línea ***

> **mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);**

*** no se si también tenga que hacerlo así en Swift y como lo tendría que hacer? ¿Me pueden ayudar?

el codigo que tengo en swift es este:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.misitio.com/")
        let req = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


}
```

Comment: ¡Hola! `UIWebView` ya está obsoleto, trata de utilizar mejor `WKWebView`. Es muy similar pero por detrás tiene toda la tecnología de WebKit. Yo lo utilizo y no tengo problema con mis scripts, espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ya lo resolvi amigos**, al final el error estaba en mi sitio web ya que el webView se pasaba por alto el requerido `<input type="text" name="nombre" required/>` y tuve que revalidar y ordenar bien mis archivos javaScripts ya que tambien alli tenia unos errorsitos, al final logre leer en un varios foros que el WebView en swift no se necesita habilitar javascript por que al final ya lo trae por default, gracias por su ayuda amigos.